# Intersection between multiple images in Xcode

Tags: c++, iphone, xcode, image

Hey guys i have been making a game in which a user presses a button and every time he presses that button, the screens adds a new UIImageView (which is the same every time). These UIImageViews are separately draggable with the UITouch function. But i want them to detect a intersection as well!
And i want to know which two UIImageViews intersected so i can change the image-url of the two UIImageViews which are intersected.

```
-(IBAction)ClTouched:(id)sender {

imgView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 20, 80, 80)];
imgView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imgView2.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
imgView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cl.png"];

[self.view addSubview:imgView2];
```

}

// To Move image with touch You can 
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    imgView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

```
// get touch event
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

if ([self.view.subviews containsObject:[touch view]]) {
    [touch view].center = touchLocation;
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imgView.frame, imgView2.frame)) {
    naam.text = @"INTERSECTION";
}
```

}

I hope this is enough information to help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You would use `CGRectIntersectsRect()` to see if any UIImageView is intersecting with another. Example below..

**EDIT: Realized afterwards that you  already implemented the `CGRectIntersectsRect()` method. If you have an array of all the other images that you can access, while dragging said image you want to compare, you can do something like this**

```
   for(UIImageView *image in yourArrayOfImages) {

         if(CGRectIntersectsRect(self.frame,[image frame])) {

              NSLog(@"self overlaps %@",image);
              //Now you know self is overlapping `image`, change the URL.

          }

    }
```

Being that you have multiples of these images, you would have to do a for loop through all your images and use above method of determining what image(s) are intersecting.

Comment: This won't work because if you look close to the code you see that imgView2 is added every time you press the button (which it is ought to do) but i can't do : if(CGRectIntersectsRect([imgView2 frame],[imgView2 frame])) {

      NSLog(@"Image2 and Image2 Overlap");

} Which will result in the fact that it intersects always.

Comment: Keep a referenced array storing all the added Images, is what you should be doing. This way you have something to check against.

Comment: I think i don't get you. I now have: `
    imgView2.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    
    for(UIImageView *image in images) {
        
        if(CGRectIntersectsRect([touch view].frame,[image frame])) {
            
            naam.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self overlaps %@",imgView2];
            
        }
        
    }

}` But can't see how this will solve

Answer (score 1):

**My Approach**

I had a similar issue in a game I created where targets appeared on the screen with different colors and properties. The way I approached it was using an NSMutableDictionary and storing each target which was a button, and then removing them when I stopped using them.

**Creating Images**

I would create a new UIImageView every time the user pressed that button and then store it in a dictionary that contains every UIImageView. I would store them with a unique key like "1" or "2". That way you could save the number as a Tag within the image and then get the number later which is actually the key of the UIImageView. In other words, the tag of the UIImageView is the same as the key value as it's stored in the dictionary.

**Collision**

I have come across this problem as well, and I came up with a solution.

```
-(BOOL) checkIfFrame:(CGRect)frameOne collidesWithFrame:(CGRect)frameTwo {
    return (CGRectIntersectsRect(frameOne, frameTwo));
}
```

This method returns a TRUE or FALSE statement if `frameA` collides with `frameB`.

**Example of NSMutableDictionary Usage**

```
NSMutableDictionary * imageViewsDictionary;
int lastImageViewNumber = 0;

-(IBAction *) addNewImageView {
    UIImageView * newImageView;

    newImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""]; //Your Image
    newImageView.frame = CGRectMake:(0, 0, 0, 0); //Your Frame
    newImageView.tag = lastImageViewNumber;

    NSString * currentKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", lastImageViewNumber];
    [imageViewsDictionary setObject:newImageView forKey:currentKey];

    [self.view addSubview:newImageView];

    lastImageViewNumber ++;
}

-(void) removeImageView:(id)sender {
    UIImageView * imageView = (UIImageView *)sender;

    [imageView removeFromSuperview];

    NSString * key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", imageView.tag];
    [imageViewsDictionary removeObjectForKey:key];

    lastImageViewNumber --;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, and how / where should i call this BOOL?

Comment: You should call this whenever you would like to know if an object intersects another object. One way to do this is by creating a timer which runs a different method consecutively which then runs this method to check if an object collides with another.